# Does Java support variable variables?

Tags: java

Such as in PHP:

```
<?php
$a = 'hello';
$$a = 'world';

echo $hello;
// Prints out "world"
?>
```

I need to create an unknown number of HashMaps on the fly (which are each placed into an arraylist). Please say if there's an easier or more Java-centric way. Thanks.

Comment: my head hurts, what the heck?

Comment: @GarethDavis , it is basically a way to reference a variable using a string, if `$a = "hello";`, then `$$a="world";` is equivalent to `$hello="world";`, it used the string as a variable name... this actually can be extremely powerful when used well, thanks to it, it made class builds for json encoding purposes a walk in the park, literally took 1 line to do with it; 
example:
`function addParam($key,$val){$this->${$key} = $val }`.
a new variable under the class gets created out of nothing at runtime.

Comment: @bakriawad think I got it, thanks...but head still hurts (9 years later)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best you can do is have a HashMap of HashMaps.  For example:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> m = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
// not set up strings pointing to the maps.
m.put("foo", new HashMap<String,String>());
```

Comment: I believe `Map<String,Object>` would fit better to match PHP's environment.
Obviously checks of `map.get("key") instanceof Object.class` would have to be used for non string objects, for primitive types you would need to use their object form instead , i.e. `map.put("key",new Integer(5));`

Answer (score 2):

Its not called variable variables in java.

Its called reflection.

Take a look at java.lang.reflect package docs for details.

You can do all such sorts of things using reflection.

Bestoes,

jrh.

Comment: Well, you can, but it's not a good idea. For various reasons, particularly type safety and performance, reflection should generally only be used as a last resort. Here just using a Map (as described in other answers) is more appropriate.

Comment: No, the OP wants to create variables with a name determined at runtime. But there are no variable names at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not support what you just did in PHP.

To do something similar you should just make a `List<Map<>>` and store your `HashMap`s in there.  You could use a `HashMap` of `HashMaps`.

A 'variable variable' in Java is an array or List or some sort of data structure with varying size.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You would do something like

```
List<Map<String,String> myMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>()
```

and then in your loop you would do:

```
Map<String,String> newMap = new Hashtable<String,String>();
//do stuff with newMap
myMaps.add(newMap);
```