# Java / Android self naming

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

I am about to start developing an Android application and had a question if in Java there self naming. For instance say I had a variable named dog that held the value of scruffy.

Could I then create a variable named scruffy from that variable. In PHP it would be `$$dog`. That would make a variable with the name scruffy.

If this is possible please provide example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, `$$dog`, or *self naming* as you refer to it as, has a special name. It is known as [*variable variables*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Android is written in Java, which does not have variable variables support.

See this related question, [Does Java support variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944677/does-java-support-variable-variables) for a possible work-around.

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect will accept ur answer when it let's me